# Can't boot into Ubuntu 20.04 — EFI partition problem?

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, grub-efi

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine whose main internal drive has 3 partitions:

- `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, EFI system partition, fat32, 512 Mb
- `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, unlocked ext4 partition, 732 Mb
- `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, encrypted LVM partition, 475 Gb

It used to work perfectly, but for a few days I can't enter into Ubuntu. I don't know what happened. Now the PC boots into GNU GRUB version 2.04 (why?), then I have to click for a normal boot and it shows this error message:

```
Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
Cannot process volume group vgubuntu
Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crypt: _
```

Then I can enter the right password, but the boot always fails a few seconds later. Everything is blocked after a lot of error messages.

I have tried to adapt [those instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688786) and a few others (notably [this](https://1729.org.uk/posts/ubuntu-vg-not-found/)) to my case. Here is what I did:

- Booted into Ubuntu (“Try Ubuntu”) using an external drive.
- Launched the Terminal app and entered this:

`sudo -i`

`cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt` (and password accepted)

```
vgchange -a y
mount /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /mnt
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /run /mnt/run
chroot /mnt
update-initramfs -c -k all
```

The generated message is `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic`.

- Then I type `exit` and `sudo reboot now`. But rebooting into the main internal drive shows the same initial error message.

Unfortunately I am not a Ubuntu professional, but I really need to repair that internal drive. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(Also, is there some repair utility/application that can be downloaded and used from the “Try Ubuntu” external drive ? I would happily try those help apps.)

Comment: When in chroot, did you also reinstall grub? Example: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&page=8&p=13602088#post13602088

Comment: @oldfred I've just reinstalled grub following the instructions on that page (thank you), but the boot is still not working (`volume group vgubuntu not found`...). — Also, the `vgs` command (in chroot) gives this: `vgubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n- <475,71g    0 ` I suppose vgubuntu exists but is not recognized by grub?

Comment: @oldfred Tested also the `vgdisplay` command (in chroot) and `vgubuntu` seems to be stated as present, once again. Here is what `vgdisplay` returns: ` VG Name               vgubuntu […] Format                lvm2 […] VG Access             read/write […] VG Status             resizable […] VG Size               <475,71 GiB`, etc.

Comment: I am familiar with grub & UEFI boot, but do not know LVM,other than having seen other posts on similar issues. One user with LVM  (but not encryption) says if you cannot fix it in an hour, just reinstall & restore from backup. That should only take an hour, if backup is good. I do not believe it is related to efi partition as in title. You may want a new question with LVM/encryption in title, so those that know LVM may respond.

Comment: @oldfred I'm not a Ubuntu specialist, and in my case I find very strange that the 3 partitions (incl. encrypted) seem to be in good state, and all data preserved. I suspect that the boot problem (`Volume group "vgubuntu" not found`) is minor, can be easily corrected (how?), but I might be wrong.

Comment: If the reinstall of grub works, your ESP should refer to grub in /boot and grub in /boot partition should ask to decrypt LVM & load encrypted partition. Perhaps grub not decrypting install as part of boot. Do not know details, but would expect reinstall of grub with encrypted / would set correct parameters in grub. But those that know LVM/encrypted may know details.

Comment: can you also post `/etc/fstab`? maybe try updating grub, and/or changing `/dev/mapper/...` in /etc/fstab to `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt`. and how does boot fail? do you have any error messages? maybe you can check out `/var/log/syslog` for more hints

Comment: @Cagri Here is `/etc/fstab`:
`# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=b3a398dd-1251-4df1-a7cd-4aa1accadbed /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=C123-ECCF  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0` (Sorry, I don't know how to insert line breaks here.)

Comment: @Cagri Just changed `/etc/fstab` as you suggested (`/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt`), but there is no difference in boot. Also, `/var/log/syslog` is an empty file.

Comment: I have just post a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428443/backup-encrypted-ubuntu-luks-lvm-partition-then-replace-a-new-luks-lvm-partitio) suggesting a totally different method to solve the problem.