# Backup encrypted Ubuntu LUKS/LVM partition, then replace a new LUKS/LVM partition with it

Tags: boot, 20.04, backup, luks, restore

Since a number of days, a Ubuntu 20.04 machine won't boot. Its internal drive has 3 partitions, and the boot problem seems to come from partition 1 and/or 2:

1. `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, EFI system partition, fat32, 512 Mb
2. `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, unlocked ext4 partition, 732 Mb
3. `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, encrypted LUKS/LVM partition, 475 Gb

I described the boot problem in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428269/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-20-04-efi-partition-problem), but now I would like to try a very different method:

1. From an external Ubuntu 20.04 drive (“Try Ubuntu”), backup and archive the whole `/dev/nvme0n1p3` encrypted LUKS/LVM partition on another external drive, for instance as an `.iso` or similar giant file. (What best method or tool to use? GParted? CloneZilla? A command in Terminal? Another thing?)
2. Totally reinstall a brand new Ubuntu 20.04 in the internal drive with 3 similar partitions, in order to resolve the boot problem.
3. Boot into the new Ubuntu 20.04 (internal drive) to verify that everything is OK, especially the partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` (LUKS/LVM, but no personal data in it).
4. Reboot from the external Ubuntu drive (“Try Ubuntu”) and replace the “new” `/dev/nvme0n1p3` internal partition with the “old” `/dev/nvme0n1p3` backup — i.e. fully restore the original LUKS/LVM partition.

**Is it possible?** Or is it just a ridiculous dream?
If it is possible, what is the best way to do it?

(As I said, I have already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428269/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-20-04-efi-partition-problem) but it was a failure for me.)

Comment: #1 Seems like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line

Comment: Image backups of a partition will not normally work with UEFI/gpt. Your gpt partition has GUID in partition table, backup partition table & partition. If try to replace a partition its GUID will not match. Also UUIDs must match. There are ways to change GUID, but not for beginners. Generally better to just backup data, no need for Ubuntu system, as you are reinstalling it. I use rsync to copy data, but one copy is not a backup procedure. I copy to multiple drives & critical data to DVDs at different times. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456011 Do not know about LVM snapshots.